# call functions onload of page in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make the make the slideDown function onload of my page.
When i removed the line:  `$("#flip").click(function()` in the following code in order to make the function execute onload of page not in click, it didn't work.
How can i call a function onload of page or when some condition happen?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
</script>

<style> 
#panel, #flip {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
    border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code works fine without the click handler.. reproduce the error in a fiddle or a snippet please. and please tell me that `$("#flip").click(function()` is not the **only** line you removed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
});
```

Comment: there is no meaning in waiting for the window to load after waiting for the dom to be created. the ` $(window).load` is enough, and in op's case the `$(document).ready` is enough too.

Comment: As OP has not mentioned any error or anything else, its bit difficult to guess what OP wants to achieve. I know its useless to put it there.

Comment: regardless of the reason, using both the way you did is always pointless.

Comment: @Engy .Mostafa You have got to be kidding rt ? Jamiec answered the same thing and he did that before everyone else, yet you accept this as a solution :P

Comment: @Arkantos - no, he accepted my solution, and then changed his mind ;) Plus 2 people downvoted me. Whatevs, im not going to lose any sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
});
```

Comment: i did that but it didn't work with me so i asked the question and i know i recognized that i didn't remove the braces when i removed the line `$("#flip").click(function(){` and because of that it didn't work.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

The problem with your code is that you're invoking `slideDown()` only when someone clicks on your `flip` element but you wish to do it on page load, so you can use jQuery's `document.ready` handler itself do that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
});
```

This will slideDown the panel when `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired which happens when all your scripts and markup are downloaded but your css and images are still downloading.

If you really want to slideDown the panel, only when the page is completely loaded i.e., markup,all scripts, images and css files are downloaded and processed, then you can listen for `load` event of the window like this

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to call on the document load as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // this will run on document load
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");

    // this will run every time you click on the div and you can add your custom logic to slide it up or down here
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

Here is demon on [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5o1ycyaa/1/)